# Can I blacklist certain types of songs on Pandora?

Tags: music, pandora

I enjoy the majority of the music that Pandora plays for me. However, I highly prefer studio versions over Glee covers or KCRW live performances.

I'd like to make it clear to Pandora that I am not interested in live performances and covers of the songs that I enjoy, but oftentimes those songs will come up as the live performances or covers before the original shows up. I fear that giving the non-studio version a thumbs down will reduce my chances of later hearing the studio version.

Does Pandora have a way of saying "I dislike live performances" or "I dislike cover bands"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that if you vote them down often enough, Pandora will get the hang of it. Pandora works by finding similarities in the traits of what you like or dislike. It won't be long before Pandora figures out that what your dislikes have mostly in common is that they are Glee covers or KCRW live peromances... And before long, you should hear less of them.

Just to be sure, you could like the studio versions and dislike the Glee covers or KCRW performances.

Comment: Not true. Been thumbing down live versions of songs for years, Pandora doesn't seem to learn the connection.

Comment: Pandora stinks!

Comment: You should probably merge your accounts so that you can get control back of your answers. Use [contact us](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page, and in the drop down for the issue you want to resolve, choose "I need to merge user profiles".